# Are there disadvantages to splitting a class's methods across different extensions?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, extension-methods

I'm writing an API service (called `ApiService`) that handles calls to a server which create, read, update and delete many different types of data. Each type of data has its own set of calls e.g. `postsList`, `postCreate`, `postRead`, `postUpdate` and `postDelete`.

If there are say 7 different types of data each with at least 5 API calls then the `ApiService` class becomes large and cumbersome to work with (say >3000 lines). I want to find a way to segment the API service so it can be worked on more easily, but still allow for my app to find any given API call it needs to through only the base API service, rather than having to pull in a `PostsApiService` or `CommentsApiService` when it needs to make a particular API call.

A way to I've thought of which achieves what I'm looking is through `extension`s. I can keep each `extension` in its own file and use the `part of` and `part` directives so the extensions are included in the base file containing the original API service and when `ApiService` is used across the app I can access all the extension methods:

```dart
// post_api.dart

part of 'api_service.dart';

extension PostApi on ApiService {
  Future<List<Posts>> posts() {
    ...
  }

  Future<List<Posts>> postCreate() {
    ...
  }

  ...
}

// api_service.dart

part 'post_api.dart';

class ApiService {
  ...
}
```

I quite like this approach, it helps me reason about the different aspects of the Api much more easily than before but it does feel **quite hacky**. Additionally since the base `ApiService` doesn't have any methods of its own, I feel like I'm misusing darts extension functionality.

Does this way open me up to all sorts of unforeseen complications, performance issues or bad practises? Is there a better way to achieve the segmentation I'm looking for?

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that virtual dispatch won't work for extension methods, so derived classes won't be able to override them as usual.  Similarly, there won't be any way to enforce that a class that `implements ApiService` provides the same methods.  You possibly don't care about either of these, but if so, then you also should consider why you want an `ApiService` class at all instead of making all of the methods freestanding functions.

Comment: That's a good point. In the general flow of the project I don't really care or need to care about overriding methods or have classes that implement `ApiService`, but implementing `ApiService` is something that may be required when writing tests for the project so it can be mocked.